# Tomcat server.xml SSLEnable issue

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Here I'm having a problem with server.xml file configuration on tomcat(8.0.9)
my tomcat works when SSLEnabled="false" but otherwise it 
provides "This webpage is not available" or "SSL Connection error"
to get additional information I checked log file but
it doesn't give any exception or error.

below is the main part of my server.xml file

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
             keystoreFile="/home/tomcat_home/conf/some.jks"
           keystorePass="somePW"
            SSLEnabled="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
           minSpareThreads="5"
           maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="true"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100"
            ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    >
```

please give me your kind advices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run https on port 8443. Change the connectors to this and change the password to fit your keystore:

```
<Connector port="8080" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" keystorePass="changeit" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```